# Mura CMS - Linking a navigation item to another item

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, mura

I have a multilevel menu. I need it so that if the user clicks on a top level menu, they are taken to one of their children. 
For example..

```
- Products (top level)
-->Product 1 (sub)
-->Product 2 (sub)
-->Product 3 (sub)
```

I need to set it up so that if the user clicks on "Products", it opens "Product 1" instead of Products?

Any suggestions on how I could do this? I'm sure it could be done, but I just can't find anything on it, nor work it out..

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: A hacky way of doing it would be to setup a layout template that has the relevant cflocation call inside it, then assign that to the products page. (Would also need to set appropriate inheritance for that, so child templates didn't use it.)

Comment: Or, a more with-the-grain way might be creating a Class Extension for a custom page type that looks up its first child and performs the appropriate redirect, then using that for Products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm loving Mura more each day.  Thanks to CatherineMM at the Mura Forums for the most simple way to achieve this:

"If you add "Go to First Child" (under System) in the Display Objects for Products, you should be all set!".

To do what my questions asks:

1. The top level Menu item (Products).
2. Go to "Layout & Objects".
3. Under 'Content Objects" select "System".
4. Then "Go to first child" and move into main content area.

That's it.. then when I click 'Products', it just opens 'Product1'.

Answer (score 0):

If this menu is query driven, you might be able to use the group attribute of cfoutput.  Something like this:

```
<cfoutput query="yourquery" group="TopLevel">
<a href="somewhere.cfm?somevariable="#fieldfromquery#">#TopLevel"</a>
<cfoutput>
<a href="somewhere.cfm?somevariable="#fieldfromquery#">#NextLevel"</a>
</cfoutput>
</cfoutput>
```

The group level and the first ungrouped level will be reading the same record in your query.